# Cómo puedo organizar el xpath para obtener el "src"?

Tags: javascript

AYUDA PLS, ¿Cómo puedo organizar el **xpath** para obtener el `src` de éste script?
he intentado con: `script/text()` y me da como resultado todo el texto, solo quiero el `src`.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var videos = {'1':['<div id="driver"><iframe width="100%" height="520"  src="https://google.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>']};
</script>
```

Comment: No es la solucion mas eficiente, pero una: ¿`<div id="hidden" style="display:none;"></div><!--Creamos un contenedor oculto para insertar el elemento.--><script>let contenedor=document.getElementById("hidden");contenedor.innerHTML=videos['1'][0];/*Isertamos el elemento por medio de la cadena videos['1'][0] que contiene el iframe dentro del contenedor invisible.*/ 
let src= document.querySelector("#driver iframe").getAttribute("src");alert(src);contenedor.innerHTML="";/*Eliminamos el elemento creado despues de obtener el src.*/</script>`?

Comment: O esto fué que entendí de la pregunta.